# How to search in vector of structure by a structure attribute?

Tags: c++, search, vector, find, structure

I have a Vector of structure that is sorted on based of a variable.

For ex:

```
struct Client {
string name;
int sm_index;
int client_id;
int user_id;

Client(string str, int x,  int y,  int c) : name(str), sm_index(x), client_id(y),user_id(c){}
}
```

Sorted on based of **sm_index**

How can i find and fetch the data of that struture whose sm_index matches our target structure.

We have below vector and no. structures added in to it.

For ex:

```
vector <client> CLIENT;

    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Rahul",8,1,13));
    CLIENT.push_back (Client("Sahil",12,3,12));
    CLIENT.push_back (Client("Ramesh",1,4,11));
    CLIENT.push_back (Client("Suresh",5,5,10));
    CLIENT.push_back (Client("Ganesh",86,6,9));
    CLIENT.push_back (Client("Gagan",4,7,8));
```

How to find the structure whose sm_index value is equal to 5.

I tried find() function, but unable to understand how to use it.

Comment: Use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a suitable functor or [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: `find_if(CLIENT.cbegin(), CLIENT.cend(), [](const auto& v) { return v.sm_index == 5; }`

Comment: If `CLIENT` has an entity semantic, overleading `operator==` for it would make sense and allow `std::find` to search for a specific client.

Comment: You say "Sorted on based of `sm_index`" but in your example the vector is not sorted by `sm_index`. Whether the vector is sorted or not makes a difference on what algorithm to use.

Comment: My Vector is sorted on based of sm_index by using below code: std::sort(CLIENT.begin(), CLIENT.end()); overloading  bool operator<(const Client& a) const
    {
        return sm_index < a.sm_index;
    }

Comment: @VishalBhatia I suggest you update the code in your question to include that as that is quite important.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do that simply by iterating through the vector and comparing for the attribute. I guess you are not looking for optimizing procedure for this.

```
for( auto iter = CLIENT.begin(); iter != CLIENT.end() ; iter++ )
{
    if( iter->sm_index == 5 ) // compare attribute for your structure
        std::cout << " Found" << std::endl;
}
```

**Edited**

Here is a faster approach with `std::binary_search`.

```
Client target("",0, 5, 0);

bool found = std::binary_search( CLIENT.begin(), CLIENT.end(), target, []( Client a, Client b ){ return a.client_id < b.client_id; } );

found ? std::cout << "Found" << std::endl : std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
```

Comment: My main aim is to search fast and iterating through vector and find_if both does the same thing linear search but i am looking for binary search as i have my vector sorted. Default binary_search function returns the boolean not iterator. Am thinking write my own binary_search function for same cause.

Comment: @VishalBhatia `std::binary_search` is slightly badly named, you probably want [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) or [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range). See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Yola, here's a ready made code snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct Client {
    std::string name;
    int sm_index;
    int client_id;
    int user_id;

    Client(std::string str, int x,  int y,  int c)
        : name(str), sm_index(x), client_id(y), user_id(c)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Client> CLIENT;

    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Rahul",8,1,13));
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Sahil",12,3,12));
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Ramesh",1,4,11));
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Suresh",5,5,10));
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Ganesh",86,6,9));
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Gagan",4,7,8));

    auto it = std::find_if(CLIENT.begin(), CLIENT.end(),[](const Client& v) { 
        return v.sm_index == 8;
    });
    if (it != CLIENT.end())
    {
      std::cout <<  (*it).name << "\n"; 
    }    
}
```

Comment: It's giving me error (const auto& v) auto is not allowed here.

Comment: @VishalBhatia this answer assumes c++11. If not, please tag your question with the specific flavour of C++ you are using (c++98, microsoft c++, ...)

Comment: @VishalBhatia : In place of auto keyword you can use Client here, if your compiler is older version. See edited.

Comment: Prefer using a binary search on sorted data instead of a linear search.

Answer (score 0):

If your `std::vector` is sorted by `sm_index` then you can use a binary search to find elements matching `sm_index`. This will be faster than `std::find_if`.

The C++ standard library provides a few algorithms for doing binary search. [`std::equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range) can be used to find multiple elements with matching `sm_index` but if you only want to find one element that has the matching `sm_index` then you can use [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

struct Client {
    std::string name;
    int sm_index;
    int client_id;
    int user_id;

    Client(std::string str, int x,  int y,  int c)
        : name(str), sm_index(x), client_id(y), user_id(c)
    {}

   bool operator<(const Client& a) const { return sm_index < a.sm_index; }
};


int main() {
    std::vector<Client> CLIENT;
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Rahul",8,1,13));
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Sahil",12,3,12));
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Ramesh",1,4,11));
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Suresh",5,5,10));
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Ganesh",86,6,9));
    CLIENT.push_back(Client("Gagan",4,7,8));
    std::sort(CLIENT.begin(), CLIENT.end()); 

    Client target("", 5, 0, 0);
    std::vector<Client>::iterator it = std::lower_bound(CLIENT.begin(), CLIENT.end(), target);
    if (it != CLIENT.end()) {
      std::cout <<  it->name << "\n"; 
    }    
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ErwX9EYjFUqtrzJU).